How to tell if a model is generative vs. predictive?
How does one tell if a given model is generative AI or predictive AI?
Do generative models have more outputs than inputs and vice versa for predictive models?

It's hard nowadays to draw a distinct line between the two with the advent of conditional generation and normalizing flow
Usually, we say that is generative if you try to model the joint probability $p(x,y)$, whereas discriminative models try to model the marginal $p(y|x)$
However, generative model aims at sampling from such learned distribution, where usually instead discriminative models are only interested in some statistics of it (such as the mode)

I would lead with and emphasize sampling, a lot of sequence generators are predictive models of distribution, plus a separate sampling routine

@NeilSlater yup, though they start from the hypothesis of modelling $p(x)$ and they factor it as $\prod p(x_i | x_{j<i})$, and so it falls back to the usual classification problem
